# Real image the complex polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $p(z)=z^4-6z^2+25<0$

I think that the solution for this problem is the following:

$$p(z)=z^4-6z^2+25=(z^2-3)^2+16$$

Thus,

$$p(z)<0 \Leftrightarrow (z^2-3)^2+16<0 \Leftrightarrow (z^2-3)^2<-16$$

But, I see not how find $z$.

Comment: Do you mean $\Re p(z)>0$\,?

Comment: as @Maryam said, it makes no sense to talk about inequalities with complex numbers. it's the real part of $p$ that should be greater than $0$ or what else?

Comment: @Ant: It does: find $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $p(z) \in \Bbb R$ and $p(z) < 0$.

Comment: @AlexM. well that's different! ;-) and personally I have never encountered this sort of "silent conversion", it's always spelled out

Answer (score 1):

Solve it as a quadratic for $z^2$, then take the square roots of your solutions.

Comment: I think the issue here is with finding *complex* solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^2-3=4ki$$,any $$|k|>1,z=\sqrt{(3-4ki)}$$.